# How to play in a LAN world with shared account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my sister are using the same account and we really want to play together in a "LAN world". I have changed the display name, but I am still using her account and I have searched this set up on YouTube and Internet. People says that's it worked to them.

But when I join her LAN world it says "connection lost. you logged from another location".
Please guys, I really need help!

Answer (score 4):

You can't play together in a LAN world if you only have one account between you. You'll need to buy one each in order to play together.